# Why is MessageDigest returning same byte[] value for different strings

Tags: java, sha

I am trying to practice java cryptography, but I noticed when I try to get the byte array of certain strings the byte array is always the same, why is this?

Here is my code snippet :

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            String message = "you are welcome";
            messageDigest.update(message.getBytes());
            byte[] md = messageDigest.digest();

            System.out.println(md);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            System.out.println("no such algorithm");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and no matter the value of my message variable, the result always printed out is `[B@1540e19d`

but what makes me more curious is when I convert my byte[] md into hex values,

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            String message = "thank you";
            messageDigest.update(message.getBytes());
            byte[] md = messageDigest.digest();

            System.out.println(md);

            //Converting the byte array in to HexString format
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0;i< md.length;i++) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & md[i]));
            }
            System.out.println("Hex format : " + hexString.toString());

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            System.out.println("no such algorithm");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

it produces totally different values for my StringBuffer hexString even the byte[] md is the same for two different strings. Please, could someone explain?

Comment: @chrylis can you please remove your duplicate flag, as this question has not been asked before, thank you.

Comment: This is a duplicate. You are printing `md` incorrectly.

Comment: You aren't printing the contents of the array, you are printing the `toString()` value of an array, which for a byte array is something like `[B@12345668`,where the number is the identity hashcode of the array. It is entirely unrelated to the contents of the array.